# @Resource datasource breaking DB connection

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, jboss, wildfly

I recently wrote a class, in my web application, for parsing a huge XML file and feed a db table with its content. My application is running on Wildfly9, and uses JPA with Hibernate provider to handle a MySQL DB.

The AS configuration is pretty standard, I just added my datasource conf:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/spazio_visione" pool-name="spazio_visione" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spazio_visione?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>myuser</user-name>
                        <password>mypasswd</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

And here's my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="backoffice" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/spazio_visione</jta-data-source>        
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>            
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />            
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> -->       
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Everything has always worked fine, using JPA entities to manage my domain model.

Back to my parser... actually, for many reasons, it needs to use native JDBC queries to insert my data in the db. Here's the code:

```
public class XMLFeedParser extends DefaultHandler {

    @Inject Logger logger;
    @Resource(lookup="java:jboss/datasources/spazio_visione") DataSource datasource;

    private static final int STATEMENT_BATCH_THRESHOLD = 1000;      
    private MyXMLFeedItem item; 

    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement ps;

    public XMLFeedParser() {

    }

    protected void initParser() throws SQLException {

        connection = datasource.getConnection();    

        Statement deleteStatement = connection.createStatement();
        deleteStatement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id_feed = "+feed.getId());
        deleteStatement.close();

        ps = connection.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO mytable "
                + "( first, second, ...) "
                + "values ( ?, ?, ... )"
                );
    }

    protected void finalizeParser() throws SQLException {
        if (ps!=null) {
            ps.executeBatch();
            ps.close();
        }
        if (connection!=null) {
            connection.close();
        }       
    }

    public void parseAndWriteToDatabase(String filePath) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, SQLException {

        File file = Paths.get(filePath).toFile();       

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();          
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        initParser();
        saxParser.parse(file, this);
        finalizeParser();               
    }

    private void writeToDb(MyXMLFeedItem item) {

        try {

            ps.setString(1, "first");
            ps.setString(2, "second");
            // ...
            ps.addBatch();

            if ( counter % STATEMENT_BATCH_THRESHOLD == 0 ) {
                ps.executeBatch();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {              
            logger.severe(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qualifiedName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {       
        // ...parsing logic
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        // ...parsing logic
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qualifiedName) throws SAXException {
        // calls writeToDb() for each record found
    }

}
```

My XMLFeedParser is injected (using @Inject) in one of my EJBs, which will call parseAndWriteToDatabase() method. It works!

The pain starts here. Since the end of the parsing, my application begins giving errors in other points, just randomly. The stacktrace looks like this:

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/spazio_visione
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:646)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:552)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:737)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 165 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:553)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:622)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:594)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:579)
    ... 168 more
```

It looks like I didn't close the connection, but that's not true!
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities what could go wrong. First, you are opening the connection in `initParser()`, but closing it in `finalizeParser()`, without using finally. If an exception is thrown, the connection is not closed. It would still be better to use try-with-resources.

Another potential problem is that the class is not thread-safe. For example, if an instance is used without synchronization, if you call `XMLFeedParser.initParser()` two times before `finalizeParser()`, you may lose your reference to `connection` which is then never closed (how does your EJB which injects the `XMLFeedParser` look like?)

edit: using try-with-resources:
it depends where you need your `Connection`. you could open the connection in `parseAndWriteToDatabase()` and pass it to the methods in which you need it. So you don't have to explicitly call `close()`. Also your PreparedStatements and ResultSets could be wrapped in try-with-resources.

for example something like:

```
 public void parseAndWriteToDatabase(String filePath) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, SQLException {

    // ...
    try (Connection connection = getDataSource().getConnection();)
    {
    initParser(connection);
    saxParser.parse(file, this);
    finalizeParser(connection);               
    }
}
```

So when your `Connection` and other variables are not members of the class, you don't have to worry about other threads accessing them.

Comment: Actually, your answer put me in the right way!
I wasn't checking the exceptions from the parser and the finalize wasn't always called.
Can you please enrich the answer with a try with resources example code? ty

Comment: added example for try-with-resources